# edit-comments.php in Admin - how to change 'Comments' title?

Tags: comments, admin

How can I change the title 'Comments' on the  edit-comments.php page in the admin area? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change 'Comments' to 'something' but it from admin side. Please follow steps:

1> Go to Appearance -> Editor in your WordPress dashboard (In the list of theme files, on the right, click on “Theme Functions” to open your functions.php file)

2> Enter the following code in your functions.php file:

```
add_filter('genesis_title_comments', 'custom_comment_text');
function custom_comment_text() {
return ('<h3>What Others Are Saying:</h3>');
}
```

Make sure to add the code after this line in your functions.php file:

```
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH.’/lib/init.php’);
```

3> Now look at your site. The “Comments” title should be replaced with our text "something".

Please let me know if you face any query/concern regarding this.

Thanks!